# clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) compiling cython

Tags: python, cython, macos-monterey

Since I upgraded macOS to Monterey, I couldn’t compile the Cython file with this command:
*python setup.py build_ext --inplace*.
I’m getting this error:

`ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/opt/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64 clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1`
How can I fix it?